# Code works in Firefox but neither in IE nor Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I am creating a jquery animation with lots of effects and responsive to some of users actions but code works fine with firefox and not in ie or chrome here is my code

```
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#wires').effect("shake", { times:3000,  distance:31  }, 300).css('z-index','-1');
                //$('#wires').css('z-index','-1');
                $('#baccha').css('z-index','99999999999999999999');
                $("#saman1").live('click',function(){
                    alert("s");
                                $('#i1').attr('src','char2.gif');
                                $('#i1').addClass('run');
                                $('#i1').removeClass('stand');
                    });
                $("#bird").live('click',function(){
                                $('#i1').attr('src','char1.gif');
                                $('#i1').addClass('stand');
                                $('#i1').removeClass('run');
                    });
                $('#wires').sparks([ {
                                         number: 10,
                                         speed:  5,
                                         img:    'spark.png'
                                      }]);


                $('#bird')
                    .sprite({
                        fps: 3, 
                        no_of_frames:3,
                        start_at_frame: 1


                    });
                     $('#light')
                    .sprite({
                        fps: 20, 
                        no_of_frames:3,
                        start_at_frame: 1


                    });


            });
        })(jQuery);

    </script>
```

in IE my wires div is hidden its nowhere I tried blank bg I could not see it and if I put z-index 0 then it will come front of baccha div which hides everything and in chrome my click function is not working I am getting some error resource interupted text/plain thing if you want I will post the error

Comment: I would recommend against "live". It's deprecated in favor of "on", in addition it's overkill when you're binding only to one element.

Also you should consider either caching your selectors or chaining.
EX:
$('#wires').effect("shake", { times:3000,  distance:31,  }, 300)
    .css('z-index','-1');
EX:
var $bird = $("#bird");

Each time you lookup on an id, though the most efficient form of selector, it's still a DOM traversal. DOM access is the slowest thing you can do in JS. //Sorry for the aweful formatting, it wont accept line breaks.

Comment: hi jholloman i understand the optimization of code is necessary but i tried this but everything in vein chrome says something Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Comment: are you setting the type in your script tag? EX:
<script src="foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the extra comma from these two sections:

```
    $('#bird').sprite({
        fps: 3,
        no_of_frames: 3,
        start_at_frame: 1, //remove this comma
    }) //put ; here, good practice

    $('#light').sprite({
        fps: 20,
        no_of_frames: 3,
        start_at_frame: 1, //remove this comma
    }) //put ; here, good practice
```

**EDIT1:** Missed one section, can you remove the extra comma from this as well and try again?

```
    $('#wires').effect("shake", {
        times: 3000,
        distance: 31, // remove this comma
    }, 300);
```

**EDIT2:** There's an extra `</div>` at the end just above the closing `body` tag. Remove that and try again.

**EDIT3:** The problem is with your HTML element stack and CSS. Just to make my point, remove the `margin-top: -60px` from your `floor` div styling and the click on `saman1` works.

Comment: hi jsang thank for reply but it didnt work , in chrome click function is not getting any call

Comment: One big problem with your answer ~ Chrome and newer versions of IE don't care about the _"trailing comma of death"_.

Comment: yes i removed all extras when you said first but as sparky672 said its of no use

Comment: hi i just found something interesting i linked jquery to googles cdn lib and that error didnt pop up for jquery file but there are 3 plugins which are not on any cdn so wats this error is about any idea?

Comment: Post the `error` and your `html` as well.

Comment: @user1553429, check the updated answer. Also, can you post the `error` you're getting?

Comment: hi its not error its like warning comes in chrome console anyways i uploaded my files on a server to get you and idea whats happening in different browsers , there is no preloader so just wait untill all images are loaded and tell me if you can help me just go to http://mintnow.com/s2/untitled-1.html and click the red post box to see action in firefox

Comment: hijsang i have removed files from server now if you need to c it again reply me

Comment: hi got it the problem was with zindex its not arranging well anyways thanks